# Error while trying to select cells between specified inputs to paste value

Tags: excel, date, range, date-range, vba

[image]

I'm fairly new to excel vba, but I've been looking for weeks for a way to code this script and no luck yet.

I've got a sheet where users will enter new items and details for forecasts.  each column from K on represents a fiscal week.

I would like populate each column between the "start date" and "end date" with the store count quantity of the row.  The fiscal weeks go from 201801 to 201952 (104 weeks total).

I tried to do a select case assigning a numeric value to each possible start & end date (so that I could set the `dtRange = Range(cells(r, sdate1), cells(r, edate1))`), but couldn't get that to work.  Below was my other attempt, but I'm getting a `Run time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error`.  Can anybody identify what I've done wrong or point me in the right direction to correct?

```
Sub test()
    Sub PASTEDATES()
    Dim strcnt As Integer
    Dim dtRange As Range
    Dim sdate As Variant
    Dim eDate As Variant
    Dim sdateval As Integer
    Dim eDateVal As Integer
    Dim chkbx As Object
    Dim r As Long
    Dim sdate1 As String
    Dim edate1 As String

    For r = 1 To 2000
        If Cells(r, 1).Value = True Then
            With Worksheets("DIST. INPUT FORM")

                sdate = Cells(r, 9).Value
                eDate = Cells(r, 10).Value
                strcnt = Cells(r, 8).Value

                Select Case sdate
                Case 201801
                sdate1 = 1
                Case 201802
                sdate1 = 2
                Case 201803
                sdate1 = 3
                Case 201804
                sdate1 = 4
                .
                .
                .
                Case 201950
                sdate1 = 102
                Case 201951
                sdate1 = 103
                Case 201952
                sdate1 = 104
                End Select


                Select Case eDate
                Case 201801
                edate1 = 1
                Case 201802
                edate1 = 2
                Case 201803
                edate1 = 3
                Case 201804
                edate1 = 4
                .
                .
                .
                Case 201951
                edate1 = 103
                Case 201952
                edate1 = 104
                End Select


                ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 8).Copy
                Cells(r, sdate1).Select
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, edate1).Select
                   Selection.Paste

            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: The other method that I tried to populate the range with is below: dtRange = Range(Cells(r, sdate1), Cells(r, edate1 - 1))

Range(dtRange).Value = strCnt

Comment: Your `Select Case` can be replaced by a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce your `Select Case` statement to a simple `For Loop`. Something like:

```
'/* use the same code to get your sdate and edate */
Dim sVal As Long, eVal As Long

sVal = 201801
For i = 1 to 104
    If sVal = sdate Then sdate1 = i: Exit For
    sVal = sVal + 1
Next

eVal = 201801
For i = 1 to 104
    If eVal = edate Then edate1 = i: Exit For
    eVal = eVal + 1
Next
```

Then from there, you check if you are getting the correct value for your variables.
 Not really a direct solution, but try simplifying your code first.

Comment: Thank you for your help, L42!  I wanted to do a loop originally for sDate1/eDate1, however, I run into issues when I get into the 2019 dates (since the weeks/columns go from 201801-201852, then hops over to 201901-201952).  Is there a way to adjust the loop accordingly or do I have to go back to Select Case?

Comment: I was returning the correct values for variables with the select case, and was getting the correct cell index values for dtRange, but the dtRange value was showing dtRange = Nothing.  And I was also getting the run-time error 1004..